# Этот код работает в CodeBlocks, но вызывает срабатывание точки останова в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, указатели, codeblocks, memory-management

Необходимо было считывать поток ввода посимвольно, пока не достигнет конца потока или не встретит символ переноса строки. Точка останова срабатывает, когда я пытаюсь очистить через `delete[] str` или `delete[] new_str`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i = 0, k = 10;
    char *str = new char[k];
    char c = '\0';
    str[0] = '\0';
    for (i = 0; cin.get(c) && c != '\n';) {
        str[i] = c;
        i++;
        str[i] = '\0';
        if (i >= k)
        {
            char *new_str = new char[k * 2];
            for (unsigned long i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
                new_str[i] = str[i];
            }
            delete[] str;
            str = new_str;
            delete[] new_str;
            k *= 2;
        }
    }
    cout << str;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разберем кусочек:

```
        char *new_str = new char[k * 2];
```

Выделили блок

```
        delete[] str;
```

Удалили старый блок

```
        str = new_str;
```

Сохранили адрес выделенного блока

```
        delete[] new_str;
```

Удалили его.

Если опять в цикле перейден на начало, что будет тут?

```
    str[i] = c;
```

Запись в удаленный блок памяти. а если опять дойдете до рассмотренного первым кода - то будете пытаться повторно удалить уже удаленный блок...

Странно скорее, что "в CodeBlock" ваша программа не валится...

Comment: Спасибо большое) буду думать дальше